# MySQL / PHP - Display all rows from table except one single row

Tags: php, mysql

me again!

So I'm wondering what the sequel/php code is to display all the rows in a table except one row. So display row 1, 2, 3 and 4 and every column, but don't display anything to do with row 5. The reason for this is I want to display all users in a user table except the user that is looking at the list itself.

Checking which user is looking at the list is fine because I can use a variable I set aside called userid which can be used to check it against. I just don't know the SQL terminology I need to use to essentially "select * from table except this row".

Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` <> 5
```

Comment: Sorry for the simple question guys, this is just what I needed! I'm new-ish to MySQLi and its terms. :) **Edit** :: will accept in 7 mins when I can as you were the first with the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `userID` != 5
```

Replacing 5 with the current user's ID should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE userid != 'currentUser'
```

Answer (score 1):

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId != $userId" ;

$userId can contain the user defined id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT user_id = < id >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *

FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 

OVER(ORDER BY id) RowNr, id FROM tbl) t

WHERE RowNr BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Comment: This does not answer the question but actually leads onto a false trail. No row numbers or analytic functions required.